# Can't validate input [type=number] with Firefox using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, validation, firefox

I used `input[type=number]`. In chrome this input ignore any kind of char (exception e - like in w3c specification). But in Firefox you can write any char, and everything is okay.

I wrote directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
        console.log('enter')
        function fromUser(text) {
            console.log(typeof text, typeof text === 'string')
            if (typeof text === 'string' && text) {
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            }
            return undefined;
        }
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
```

But it doesn't work in Firefox 52.7.3 (64-bit). I didn't get any kind of symbol in console.log. 
The next one, I change $parsers order to:

```
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(fromUser);
```

I got symbol in console.log but in output it doesn't help. 
Next one, I can add handler (in example - only demo for 'e' symbol):

```
onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode == 69 ? false : true"
```

But there are many fields and I think it's bad solution.
At now, I rewrite all with `input[type=text]`. But I want to use `input[type=number]`. Can anybody help with it?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Muskos/pen/NYJJbP)

Comment: what version of Firefox were you using?

Comment: 52.7.3 (64-bit) debian (my friend got it on mac)

Comment: Firefox 52 [supports input type="number"](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form.number.validation.html) as well as its validation. Can you post your code that presumably allows you to type chars into it?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey did you try it? I read that they start support it in 2014 but I didnt understand what they start support...

Comment: @AlekseySolovey https://codepen.io/Muskos/pen/NYJJbP

Comment: That's a slightly broken code. Your example had `ng-model="number"` I think you needed `ng-model="result"`. Works fine without a directive (which also doesn't accept `.` / decimals)

Comment: Are you serious? Did you try it? It doesn't depends on veriable definition. In chrome you can't input char, in FF you can. Maybe I poorly explained situation?